# How to configure Assets in Angular profile

Tags: angular, themes, angular-cli, angular-config

In the styles.scss file, I import another scss file where I have custom colors:
`@import "./assets/dev/styles/colors";`
in the rest of the project, I have components where I use icons and images: `<img src="../../../../assets/dev/logo/logo-white.svg" alt="" class="logo">`

I have three profiles, 'test1', 'test2' and 'dev'.
My assets folder is structured like this:

```
assets
 ~ i18n
 ~ test1, test2, dev
   ~ favicon
   ~ icons
   ~ images
   ~ logo
   ~ styles
```

Is there a way to work with different assets depending on the profile?

Something like:

**'test1':**

```
@import "./assets/test1/styles/colors";
<img src="../../../../assets/test1/logo/logo-white.svg" alt="" class="logo">.
```

**'test2':**

```
@import "./assets/test2/styles/colors";
<img src="../../../../assets/test2/logo/logo-white.svg" alt="" class="logo">.
```

**'dev':**

```
@import "./assets/dev/styles/colors";
<img src="../../../../assets/dev/logo/logo-white.svg" alt="" class="logo">.
```

Comment: fileReplacements section in angular.json should help here, but you will have to create a separate build configuration for each build target and call build with these configurations for each env